# Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous, when $f''$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $(0,1)$. It is given that for all $x\in(0,1)$, $|f''(x)|\leq M$; where $M$ is a non-negative real number. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$

Comment: note that $f$ can be continuously extended on the boundary of $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f''$ is bounded, it follows that $f'$ is uniformly continuous by the mean value theorem. So we can extend $f'$ to the boundary and make it a continuous function on $[0,1]$. But now this is a continuous function on a compact set, and so is also bounded. So we can descend again to $f$.

Comment: using what argument is it okay to extend the boundray to make $f'$ continuous function on $[0,1]$. does that follow directly from the fact $f'$ is uniformly continuous on (0,1)? or how do you prove that the $f'$ limits in the edge points must exist?

Comment: @Jneven It is a theorem (that you can find on this site also) that a uniformly continuous function on a subspace of a metric space extends to its closure uniquely.

Comment: as I haven't learned topology yet, could you suggest a different argument for this? (I prefer using arguments I know\learned their proofs)